# SandboxRefresh Class will not run on refresh but will run in Anonymous Context

Tags: sandbox-refresh, deliverability, sandboxpostcopy

Here is my code for the SandboxRefresh class that I'm trying to run. 
The batch classes have a finish method that does attempt to send emails, and I'm wondering if the default Deliverability settings are interfering with the scripts ability to complete and the updates are getting rolled back.

```
global class SandboxRefresh implements SandboxPostCopy {
    global Organization org = [SELECT Id, isSandbox FROM Organization];
    global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
        System.debug('Org ID: ' + context.organizationId());
        System.debug('Sandbox ID: ' + context.sandboxId());
        System.debug('Sandbox Name: ' + context.sandboxName());
        // Call Batch classes

        if (org.IsSandbox == true || Test.isRunningTest()) {
            System.Debug('Sandbox detected: Begin Refresh');
            Id leadBatchId = Database.executeBatch(new LeadBatchClass(), 200);
            Id conBatchId = Database.executeBatch(new ContactBatchClass(), 200);
            Id acctBatchId = Database.executeBatch(new AccountBatchClass(), 200);
        } else {
            System.debug('You are not running this in a sandbox');
        }
    }

}
```

**Execute Anonymous Code**

```
 public class sbxContext implements SandboxContext
            {
                public ID organizationID(){return UserInfo.getOrganizationId();}
                public ID sandboxID(){return UserInfo.getOrganizationId();}
                public String sandboxName(){return 'sandbox';}
            }

            //**Declare the instance**
            sbxContext context = new sbxContext();
            sandBoxRefresh sbxRefresh = new sandBoxRefresh();
            sbxRefresh.runApexClass(context);
```

From Salesforce: 
This is what makes think the deliverability options has something to do with it.

> The SandboxPostCopy Apex class is executed at the end of the sandbox copy using a special Automated Process user that isn’t visible within the org. This user doesn’t have access to all object and features; therefore, the Apex script cannot access all objects and features. If the script fails, run the script after sandbox activation as a user with appropriate permissions.

source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm

Comment: Rollbacks in a finish method would not affect DML operations in the execute method. Are you saying the records do not get modified?

Comment: Correct. All the Accounts Contacts and Leads are coming down from Production with the same information. Even if I run this class in the Apex Class field that is presented when refreshing sandboxes.

Comment: About to make a refresh of the sandbox in a bit, and was researching the fact that there are certain things that can prevent the class from running. Was wondering if email deliverability would have something to do with it:

Comment: Just re-ran it for this months refresh. Still happened. Will play around with it for some developer sandboxes.

Comment: Just got the email that says it ran, but the class didn't do anything. Had to run from execute anonymous window to update.